# Matching JPEG signature

Tags: c, file-io, jpeg

I am trying to scan a file looking for 1MB JPEGs that would be stored contiguously.  My approach is create a structure to match the first 4 bytes with the JPEG signature and, if true, write the entire 512 buffer to a named file until I find another jpeg signature then I create a new file.  The code below creates 2 files, neither of which are readable as the first few bytes are not part of the jpeg signature.  Any ideas where I went wrong?  I tried variations of my if statement where I test for the signature but no luck thus far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t  BYTE;

typedef struct
{
    BYTE first;
    BYTE second;
    BYTE third;
    BYTE fourth;
}
JPGTEST;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    FILE* inptr = fopen("card.raw", "r");

    if (inptr == NULL)

    {

        printf("Could not open file\n");

        return 2;

    }

    FILE* outptr;

    //initialize jpeg count and variable for filename
    int count = 0;
    char name[8];

    //allocate memory
    char buffer[512];
    JPGTEST myjpg;
    int is_open = 0;

    while (fread(&buffer, 512, 1, inptr) != 0)
    {

        //test first 4 bytes to see if jpeg
        fread(&myjpg, sizeof(JPGTEST), 1, inptr);

        //if match, name and write to file

        if (myjpg.first == 0xff && myjpg.second == 0xd8 && myjpg.third == 0xff && (myjpg.fourth == 0xe0 || myjpg.fourth == 0xe1))
        {
            sprintf(name, "%03d.jpg", count);
            if (is_open == 0)
            {          
                outptr = fopen(name, "w");
                fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer),1,outptr);
                is_open = 1;
            }
            if (is_open == 1)
            {          
                fclose(outptr);
                outptr = fopen(name, "w");
                fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer),1,outptr);
                count++;
            }  

        }
        else
        {
            if (is_open == 1)
            {
                fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer),1,outptr);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(inptr);
    fclose(outptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: From a quick glance, it seems that myBuffer contains bytes 0-511, myjpeg contains bytes 512-515. Hint: don't do the second read. Check the first 4 bytes of buffer. (or write myjpeg, followed by X number of bytes. X = ??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your second **fread** inside the loop with the below:

```
        memcpy((void *)&myjpg, (void *) buffer, sizeof(JPGTEST));
```

And include string.h header file in your code for **memcpy** function.

What you are doing wrong is that after reading first 512 you are not making any use of them rather you are again reading 4 bytes without checking first 4 bytes of previously read 512 bytes.

Comment: thank you, that worked.  Guess I was moving pointer in stream twice before checking.

Comment: Suggest `memcpy(&myjpg, buffer, sizeof myjpg);`, as code can drop the unneeded `(void *)` and IMO, `sizeof var` is easier to maintain than `sizeof (type)`

Answer (score 2):

You are opening the files in **text mode**.  You need to open them in **binary mode** instead:

```
FILE* inptr = fopen("card.raw", "rb");
```

```
outptr = fopen(name, "wb");
```

Aside from that, you are calling `fread()` too many times, and just generally not managing the files correctly.

Try something more this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t  BYTE;

#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct
{
    BYTE first;
    BYTE second;
    BYTE third;
    BYTE fourth;
}
JPGTEST;
#pragma pack(pop)

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* inptr = fopen("card.raw", "rb");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file\n");
        return 2;
    }

    FILE* outptr = NULL;

    //initialize jpeg count and variable for filename
    int count = 0;
    char name[8];

    //allocate memory
    char buffer[512];
    JPGTEST myjpg;

    while (fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, inptr) > 0)
    {
        //test first 4 bytes to see if jpeg
        memcpy(&myjpg, buffer, sizeof(JPGTEST));

        //if match, name and write to file
        if ((myjpg.first == 0xff) && (myjpg.second == 0xd8) && (myjpg.third == 0xff) && ((myjpg.fourth == 0xe0) || (myjpg.fourth == 0xe1)))
        {
            if (outptr != NULL)
            {          
                fclose(outptr);
                outptr = NULL;
            }

            ++count;
            sprintf(name, "%03d.jpg", count);

            outptr = fopen(name, "wb");
        }

        if (outptr != NULL)
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, outptr);
    }

    fclose(inptr);

    if (outptr != NULL)
        fclose(outptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This solution causes a seg fault.  Am pretty sure I need to test if current file being written to is still open (i.e. still writing one of  the 20 512KB blocks). But thank you for catching the final Null check for the output file.  Forgot to test for that.

Comment: The problem was that `outptr` was not initialized to NULL, so the first loop iteration tried to write to an unopened file. I have corrected that.

Comment: Thanks.  So checking if `outptr = NULL` does the job of my `is_open` variable though much cleaner.

Comment: Did the fact that my code works using `fread()` in text mode due to it being used in a Linux environment?  Wondering why just using "r" worked for me.  I agree the "rb" is better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not resetting the file position indicator after you read into `buffer`, to do so use, `fseek`. I.e.:

```
    //test first 4 bytes to see if jpeg
    fseek (inptr, SEEK_SET, 0);
    fread(&myjpg, sizeof(JPGTEST), 1, inptr);
```

That will provide you with a test of the jpg header in `myjpg`:

```
sizeof (myjpg): 4
first: ff  second: d8  third ff  fourth:  e0
```

However, that will also cause logic issues you will have to rework. It is better to simply read the values from `buffer` as suggested by the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following to simplify your signature comparisons:

```
#include ...

#define JPEG_SIGNATURE 0xFFD8

void
reverse_bytes (void const *data, long unsigned size)
{
  char *ptr = (char *)data;
  int i = 0;
  while (i < size / 2)
    {
      char temp = ptr[i];
      ptr[i] = ptr[size - i - 1];
      ptr[size - i - 1] = temp;
      i++;
    }
}

int
main()
{
  FILE *fptr = fopen("path/to/image.jpeg", "rb");

  short bytes = 0;
  fread(&bytes, sizeof(char), sizeof(bytes), fptr);

  reverse_bytes(bytes, sizeof(bytes)); // Refer to [1]

  switch (bytes)
  {
    case JPEG_SIGNATURE: 
      printf("JPEG image!");
      break;
    default:
      printf("Unknown format!");
      break;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This can be extended to many different formats by adding more cases in the switch statement and a little more work.

This is indeed not a full or proper answer but, I hope it is helpful for others who come through this post!

**NOTE:** I omitted things like exception handling for brevity!

**References:**

1. [Why is Fread reading unsigned-int in reverse order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856419/why-is-fread-reading-unsigned-int-in-reverse-order)