# Why is Fread reading unsigned-int in reverse order?

Tags: c, binary

My binary file contains

`0400 0000 0000 0000 0400 0000 0000 0000`

When I use the following code to read the first 4 bytes in an unsigned int `inputInteger`

```
FILE *inputFile;
inputFile = fopen("./Debug/rnd_2", "rb");
unsigned int inputInteger = 0;
fread(&inputInteger, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, inputFile);
fclose(inputFile);
exit(0);
```

What i get is `inputInteger == 4`. Should it not have been 1024 considering the bit position being `00000100 00000000`?

My understanding is the first four bytes are `0400 0000`

**EDIT:** Code and the wordings of the question

Comment: Start by hexdumping the file *by character*, not by pairs of characters.

Comment: You need to be clearer about the contents of your file. What representation is that you've shown us? It obviously isn't binary. Is it one 32-bit word with the hexadecimal value 0x04000000? Something else? What? And what is `number`? And what is the endianness of the data? Does it match the endianness of your system? Many more details required; present your [MCVE].

Comment: `fread` reads a sequence of bytes from a `FILE*` and writes to a buffer.  `fread` itself is endian-agnostic.  How those written bytes are interpreted later will be dependent on your platform.

Comment: Sorry, i added the question at 3AM in the morning. Updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*fread* read the characters in order and put them in the same order in the destination, so for the same file the result will not be the same for little and big endian when you will consider back the result as an *int*

it is exactely like if you do

```
char * p = (char *) &number;

p[0] = fgetc(file);
p[1] = fgetc(file);
...
p[sizeof(int) - 1] = fgetc(file);
```

(supposing there are enough characters in the file)

> Turns out number read is 4. Is not the bits 0000 0100 0000 0000 == 1024?

depends if you are little or big endian, is 1024 or 64

---

Update after question editing

> My binary file contains
>
> 0400 0000 0000 0000 0400 0000 0000 00000000 0000 0000

that time it seem you give the values in hexa (not in base 2 as previously), so you mean your file contains

> 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

a character is on 8 bits, not on 16

- if little endian on 32 bits that gives 4 + (0<<8) + (0<<16) + (0<<24) = 4
- if big endian on 32 bits that gives (4<<24) + (0<<16) + (0<<8) + 0 = 16384

Comment: Can you please update your answer with respect to my updates. I was maybe unclear in my asking.

Comment: @BasitAnwer I did

Comment: Since the endian is only how we interpret the binary, by default when we do fread it places format in little indian representation?

Comment: @BasitAnwer if you want it is possible to say fread is little endian, but no more nor less than memcpy or any other memory copy is little endian. But _fread_ is a copy from file to array of character (or a memory block considered to be an array of cgaracter), to speak about endian is out of scope for me. The endian comes when you interpret the block of memory receiving the file contents as a number

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what i want to confirm is for me what fread did was copy the fourth byte in the first byte in my unsigned int. Third byte in the second and so forth. For me this is weird. That's not how a stream was supposed to work but that is just my opinion.

Comment: @BasitAnwer no, _fread_ copy the first character in the first byte, then the second character in the second byte and so on. And this is the same if I do not use _fread_ but _fgec_ like I say in my answer. The problem is you consider the byte order not from a pointer of char but knowing the receiver is a number, _fread_ doesn't not know the receiver will be interpreted as a number, _fread_ writes from the address it received in argument, and that address is a char*